# CalDav server proxy

Tags: proxy, caldav

Basically I want a lightweight CalDav server proxy, which passes the username, password and calendar name to a script and it will respond with either invalid user/pass, no such calendar or return the calendar.
The CalDav server would then return the appropriate response back to the server.

I will only have the calendars of the users stored locally on the server for caching purposes as I don't directly access to the users calendars. My script will try to login to an external site (out of my control in any way) and fetch the calendar by crawling the site.

If possible I would prefer if the server has wsgi support for communicating with my script.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet here is to use [sabre/dav](http://sabre.io/) and write a custom backend for it. As an example, at a company I used to work for I wrote a MongoDB backend for SabreDAV as well as getting the list of calendars from the system it was connected to. This is very similar to your use case, therefore check out [this](https://ci.open-paas.org/stash/projects/OR/repos/esn-sabre/browse) repository. You can find the backend implementation [here](https://ci.open-paas.org/stash/projects/OR/repos/esn-sabre/browse/lib/CalDAV/Backend/Mongo.php) and will need a lot of the other code to make the calendar listings work.

I would advise to do some caching and not scrape the remote site on each request, since caldav in connection with webdav-sync will want to provide updates since the last time the client synchronized, and that will be harder to do if you are scraping in the moment.